# Check if a script has any ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval

I have an application which lets clients `eval()` their code but I don't what that they make any kind of call to server(ajax).

Comment: If you can, don't check if there's an ajax call but remove the `eval()` altogether.

Comment: Not sure what you want to know.....

Comment: the eval() function can't be removed

Answer (score 2):

First, you probably shouldn't let clients eval code.

Second, even if you put some most sophisticated javascript filters in your app, that's not gonna prevent anything. A user can run any javascript in the console, and there's nothing you can do about it. Except for placing checks on server-side.